# How to consume RabbitMQ messages (runs on Windows host) inside Docker container?

Tags: php, docker, rabbitmq

I tried out an example program using PHP and RabbitMQ and it worked well

All the 3 (Client, MQ Server and Server) are running on the same machine

```
Client.php --->  Rabbit MQ Server (exe)  --->  Server.php
```

Now, I dockerized `Server.php` and I want to use the same setup.

```
Client.php --->  Rabbit MQ Server (exe)  --->  Dockerized Server.php
```

`Client.php` will send messages to `RabbitMQ Server`.  However, I am not sure how to make `docker container` to receive messages from `Rabbit MQ` which runs on `Windows host`

There are many examples which uses RabbitMQ + Application containers to do the task.

Just wanted to know whether the scenario (Docker container using Windows host program) mentioned above can be accomplished.

Comment: Use the special host name `host.docker.internal` to connect to the RabbitMQ broker (on Windows or MacOS).

Comment: @DavidMaze Sorry, where to use ?  Like this $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(host.docker.internal, 5672, 'guest', 'guest');